# Adding a PyQGIS Plugin to the Database Menu

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am developing a plugin which I would like to add to the *Database* menu instead of the default *Plugins* menu.

According to the [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html) all I have to do is add

```
category=Database
```

to my plugin's *metadata.txt*.

However, that does not have any effect. Do I have to add something in my *initGui* as well?

Currently the initGui looks like this:

```
def initGui(self):
    self.importCSV_action = QAction('Import CSV', self.iface.mainWindow())
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.importCSV_action, QtCore.SIGNAL("activated()"),self.importCSV)
    self.iface.addPluginToMenu('xxx', self.importCSV_action)
```

If I leave the *category=Database* out in my metadata.txt the plugin appears as expected in the Plugins menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The category entry in the metadata.txt is only minded as a tip for the plugin user. From the pyqgis developer cookbook: http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/plugins.html

> A corresponding “category” metadata entry exists to specify that, so
>   the plugin can be classified accordingly. This metadata entry is used
>   as tip for users and tells them where (in which menu) the plugin can
>   be found. Allowed values for “category” are: Vector, Raster, Database
>   or Web. For example, if your plugin will be available from Raster
>   menu, add this to metadata.txt

If you use the latest Plugin Builder tool the code:

```
self.iface.addPluginToMenu(self.menu,action)
```

Should be:

```
self.iface.addPluginToDatabaseMenu(self.menu,action)
```

Or in your case:

```
self.iface.addPluginToDatabaseMenu('xxx', self.importCSV_action)
```

Comment: And I even remember reading that part a while back! Works really well :-)